# Log which IPs visit WAMP intranet page?

Tags: logging, wamp, intranet

I've got several reports on our intranet (WAMP) and have been asked to see which managers make use of those reports.

I can look up their IP addresses fairly easily, but need to know the best way of recording who visits each page and which page they visit.

I know that you can use the access.log to see an overview of who visits any page hosted by the server, but is it possible to create a specific log for a specific page?

Any pointers helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work it out in the end and here's how.

In httpd.conf I added a new log format which showed me the various bits I needed to know

```
LogFormat "%h %t \"%{Referer}i\" \"%r\"" simple
```

I then created a variable so that if someone went to that specific set of pages then it would get that variable and I could log that particular web page's traffic independently of the rest of the traffic.

```
SetEnvIf Referer http://intranet-srv02/reports/hourly/ intranet_report
```

Finally I created a second log using the log format I created and the variable

```
CustomLog "logs/reportlog.log" simple env=intranet_report
```

This then provided me with the log for internal IPs that visited these reports and I could then use the command prompt command nbtstat -a ip.ip.ip.ip to find the host name and then look up which user was on that host in our login logs.